# How to show content from a Google Maps address using Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, sequelize.js, ng-map

I looked for an information for several weeks.
First, I'm using **AngularJS 1.6** and **ngMap** module.

**Here's what I'm doing:**

- I'm using a search box (with `ngMap` autocomplete) in my Homepage:

  ```
  import htmlTemplate from './searchBox.html';

  export default {

    template: htmlTemplate,

    require: {
      parent: '^home'
    },

    controller: function controller(MapsService, $log) {
      'ngInject';

      const self = this;

      this.$onInit = () => {
        $log.info('searchBox component init');
        MapsService.loadGoogleApi().then(() => {
          this.loaded = true;
          this.onPlaceChanged = function onPlaceChanged() {
            const place = this.getPlace();
            if (place.geometry) {
              self.activity.lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
              self.activity.lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
            }
          };
        });
  ```
- Also, I'm using a component which shows activities. 
  When I create an activity via my form, I fill an **address field** which uses autocomplete.

  ```
  <div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">location_on</i>
            <input ng-if="$ctrl.loaded" places-auto-complete ng-model="$ctrl.activity.address" id="icon_prefix" type="text" on-place-changed="$ctrl.onPlaceChanged()"
              class="validate">
            <label for="icon_prefix">{{'ANNOUNCE.ADDRESS' | translate}}
      </label>
  ```
- I specified that addresses **are converted in latitude / longitude**.

  ```
  MapsService.loadGoogleApi().then(() => {
      this.loaded = true;
      this.onPlaceChanged = function onPlaceChanged() {
        const place = this.getPlace();
        if (place.geometry) {
          self.activity.lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
          self.activity.lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
        }
      };
    });
  ```

**My question is:**

**How to show activities (by city) by making coincide the address of my search box and the address of my form?**

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I finded my answer. 
It's necessary to add a stored procedure into the database and create a function which will allow to get back the data.